# no matching function for call to 'fscanf'

Tags: c++, scanf

I'm trying to read a time from a file for example (12:00 A)
I need to read in all three parts. Here is what I have.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name, filename;
    ifstream inputFile;

    cout << "What is the name of the file to be provessed ";
    cin >> filename;
    inputFile.open(filename.c_str());

    getline(inputFile, name);
    fscanf (inputFile, "%d:%d %c", &startH, &startM, &startAP);
    fscanf (inputFile, "%d:%d %c", &endH, &endM, &endAP);
    inputFile >> payRate;
```

I'm getting the error from the title and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Show us the error message please.

Comment: [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) doesn't take [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) objects as the input mechanic. It uses `FILE*`. Stop mixing your C and C++.

Comment: @WhozCraig for some reason I also don't like them... :-)

Comment: @pasztorpisti heh. dance with the one you brought. (old phrase from a time when my *dad* was a teenager). =P

Comment: @WhozCraig :-) Quite true, especially in this case!

Answer (score 3):

Function `fscanf` is a standard C function that is declared in header `<cstdio>` the following way (I will show how the function is declared in header `<stdio.h>` in C. in fact the same declaration except the keyword restrict is used in C++)

```
int fscanf(FILE * restrict stream,
const char * restrict format, ...);
```

As you can see there is no parameter of type `std::ifstream`

So the compiler issues the error because it is unable to find a function with name fscanf that has the first parameter of type std::ifstream and at the same time it can not implicitly convert an object of type `std::ifstream` to a pointer of type `FILE *`

You should not mix C++ stream functions with C stream functions.

Comment: What would you recommend I use to read in a time from a file?

Comment: @user3399942  Look through the C++ localization library or write the function yourself.